# How does the error object capture the stack thought I dont' pass that in argument

Tags: javascript

I created a custom error object extending from `Error` and threw it with just the message as parameter to the constructor and calling super in the constructor without any parameters. How is `err.stack` working?

```
class MyError extends Error {
 constructor(message,err) {
    super();
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.cause = err
 }
}
```

I can get the stack though I don't pass it to super.

```
try { 
     if(i > 6 ) { 
       throw new MyError('greater than 6'); 
     } 
} catch(err) { 
   if(err instanceof MyError) {
     console.log(err.stack);  // how is err.stack working...??
   }
}
```

Comment: does MyError inherit the field, which is initialized on its own in super()?

Comment: `err.stack` is made available through prototypal inheritance - regardless of the `class` construct. It's that simple.

Comment: The stack trace can be generated without any idea of what the error *message* is.

Answer (score 0):

`stack` is part of `Error.prototype`, which gets included in `MyError` when you extend the standard `Error`. This is the real inheritance used in JS. What happens behind the scenes is something like:

```
MyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```